# Select several textboxes in a panel

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox, panel

I have several textboxes nested in a panel and I want to check if they have text or not. Although I don't want to write my code like this:

```cs
if(textbox1.Text != "" && textbox2.Text != "" ...) 
{
    ...
}
```

Is there any way to automate this and improve the general quality of the code itslef?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done very easily by using `OfType` and `All` extension methods from `System.Linq`.

```cs
var panel = new Panel
{
    Size = new Size(500, 500),
    BackColor = Color.Red
};

panel.Controls.Add(new TextBox { Text = "Value" });
panel.Controls.Add(new TextBox { Text = "Value2" });

if (panel.Controls.OfType<TextBox>().All(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.Text)))
{
    //Do something
}
```

The code in the if statement will only execute if all the Text properties of TextBoxes are not empty.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Linq extensions methods to get all Textboxes of a Panel where the property Text is not empty:

```
using System.Linq;

var textboxes = panel.Controls.OfType<TextBox>().Where(c => c.Text != "");

foreach ( TextBox textbox in textboxes )
{
  // ...
}
```

If you want to check if they are all non empty, use this:

```
if ( panel.Controls.OfType<TextBox>().All(c => c.Text != "") )
{
  // ...
}
```